# Lighting an area of the Earth Surface from LEO

Tags: low-earth-orbit, mathematics, the-sun, sunlight

What does the math look like to calculate the size of an object in LEO that when angled off the sun, would illuminate a given portion of the Earth's surface?

For example, if I wanted to "light up" a square mile of Earth's surface, how big would the reflecting object need to be to achieve this?

I'd like to see the math that calculates this.

Comment: How much light do you want?

Comment: Also, what is the shape of the area to be lit? Square? Circular? And is the light level to be constant over the entire area, or can it vary a little from center to edges, as long as it stays above a minimum value?

Comment: You might want to look into "iridium flares", where something like this happens accidentally. With a normal flat mirror, you're collecting a small amount of sun and spreading it out over a large portion of the Earth. You might be able to accomplish what you want with a parabolic mirror. Under unachievably perfect conditions, you could probably fry ants (or people) from space :)

Comment: Thanks for your questions guys. 
Dan - enough to achieve normal daylight conditions for a limited area.
Tom - At this point, whichever is the easier to achieve for a set area.
Barry - If a parabolic mirror, it would need to be deployable from the satellite (a CubeSat in particular, or constellation.)

Comment: Keep in mind that LEO isn't far away, it is fast. If you are trying to constantly illuminate a fixed point you will need a new satellite every few minutes as the previous one falls toward the horizon. Unrelated, but worth looking into is [Rjukan Norway](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20170314-the-town-that-built-a-mirror-to-catch-the-sun) that already does what you are asking on a smaller scale with the mirrors mounted on a hillside.

Comment: If your goal is to illuminate the night, LEO also has the problem that it is in the Earth's shadow for most of the night.

Comment: If you want to illuminate a square mile with full sunlight intensity, a mirror smaller than a square mile would not work.  A very simple assumption with no losses by optical diffraction and other reasons.

Comment: This has been done as an experiment: https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/how-russian-space-mirror-briefly-lit-night-180957894/

Comment: Why do you want it to be in LEO?  A Molniya or Tundra orbit would be much more suitable, as the apogee above high latitudes is more likely to remain sunlit despite the surface experiencing night time.

Comment: @Uwe That's true if you define "full sunlight intensity" as the Sun straight overhead.  Most people would experience even 1% of that at night as "full daylight" as it'd be easily bright enough for outside activities.

Comment: @gerrit: full sunlight intensity is about 100,000 Lux. 1 % of that is 1000 Lux, a TV studio illumination. A night with a full Moon is about 0.05–0.36 Lux, much less than 1 % of full daylight. Without Moon and only stars at night is about 0.001 Lux. An overcast day may be about 1000 Lux.

Comment: The chart in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lux suggests 10% of 100 kilolux could be considered "full daylight", but not 1%.

Comment: I suggested LEO as a starting point. As I am wanting to determine the size of the object in orbit to get a square mile of sunlight. As I'm using constellation CubeSats or similar, LEO seemed more realistic.

Comment: Re, "...square mile of sunlight..." You mean, like, as _bright_ as the daytime Sun? My intuition tells me (don't have time to do math) that the satellite would have to appear _at least_ as large in the sky as the Sun appears... 0.5 degree,... 300miles up...? Um,... somewhere in the neighborhood of 2.6 miles across?

Answer (score 2):

A rough calculation based on a small (less than km) mirror:

Light from a small mirror will have the sam divergence as the incident light. The Sun’s angular diameter is about 10mr. So a mirror in a 300 km orbit will create a 3km diameter spot on the earth

So the intensity of the illumination, compared to Sunlight, is just the ratio of the mirror area to that of the spot:

$$ I_{\rm{delivered}} = (r/1500m)^2 I_{\rm{sun}}$$

Comment: Diffraction will increase the divergence especially for small mirrors.

Comment: True, but it would have to be a very small mirror to have a divergence larger than the spread of light from the Sun. Your eye, a small optic, can resolve features on the Sun and moon unaided (well, except for attenuation of the Sun’s light)

Answer (score 1):

Any size of object will reflect enough light to reach the ground. The question is how much light do you want?

As a tangible near-baseline example, a Starlink satellite is visible from the ground.
[image]

They are about 2.4 m by 1.4 m in base area. ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/bsbizc/more_detailed_view_of_starlink_satellites/))

[image]

So at least an area of ~3.3 m^2 is sufficient to illuminate the ground.

Comment: Due to the high sensitivity of the human eye a satellite with a reflecting are of some square meters may be visible.

But to get a visible ilumination of the surface of Earth a much larger reflecting area will be neccessary

Comment: Though not really an answer to the question as asked, `+1` for introducing a new and more intuitive unit of measure for payload size!